# is there a function in VB.net that contains a list of ascii values

Tags: ascii

I want to write a function which accept a value parameter (lets the value x),  then generates the ASCII code of the character that comes after x in the ASCII table. For example when i call the function and pass the value "B" to the function, the function will return the ASCII value of "C"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try [`Strings.Asc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.asc?view=netframework-4.8):

```
Strings.Asc("B") + 1
```

The reverse of [`Asc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.asc?view=netframework-4.8) is [`Chr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr?view=netframework-4.8).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.asc?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Note: While `Asc` and `Chr` are suitable for ASCII character codes, they operate on character codes 0 to 255. The interpretation of 128-255 depends on the user's computer's current user settings at the time, which almost never what you want. So, `Asc` and `Chr` are red flags.

Comment: OP specifically asked about ASCII characters, *not* extended ASCII.

Comment: Yes but .NET doesn't directly support either one (except encoding or decoding byte arrays.)  AscW and ChrW are equally applicable to ASCII but don't suffer from Asc and Chr's unwanted "adaptability." So, use of Asc and Chr's should not be promoted except in the rare case where they are exactly what's needed.

Comment: Those are non-issues in this context.

Comment: Not at all. You are teaching someone about those functions yet are leaving out the very reason for their existence, which also has a high potential for misunderstanding and misuse, all while there are perfectly good alternatives.

Comment: Reread the question. It's irrelevant to the problem he's trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no list, at least not directly.

Like VB4/5/6/A/Script, C#, F#, Java, JavaScript, …, "Visual Basic" (as it is called by Microsoft since 2005) uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set for its text datatypes.

Unicode incorporates all of the characters from ASCII as Unicode's [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block with the same values in the same order.

Visual Basic and .NET do not have a list of such characters. You could note that they all are encoded by UTF-16 in one code unit (`Char`) and range from `&H0` to &H7F`.

So, except for running off the end of the ASCII range, you could do your character code number line arithmetic on UTF-16 to get the same result. Code comments would explain how you are using UTF-16 datatypes for a problem described as using ASCII.

---

```
Function Succ(C As Char) As Char
    Dim utf16 = AscW(C)

    ' Intent is to use this method only for "ASCII" characters, which have the same values in UTF-16 code units.
    If utf16 >= &H7F Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(Nameof(C), "Result must be within the C0 Controls and Basic Latin block.") 

    Return ChrW(utf16 + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: This attempt at an answer is woefully inaccurate.